# How to add a foreign key for a table that is already created?

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys

I have added a table to a database called settings. This table has a column called id (integer) which is the pirmary key.  I have also added a column called settingsID to a table called sessions. What I want to do is add a foreign key to settingsID which references the primary key.

I don't want to create a new table as it is already created. All I want to do is to references the id from the settings table in settingsID which is in sessions table.

```
ALTER TABLE Sessions ADD FOREIGN KEY (_SettingsID) REFERENCES settings (id)
```

Here is my error:

> near "FOREIGN": syntax error

Can someone tell me the right way to approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: you can't.

This is documented as part of the [SQL Features That SQLite Does Not Implement](https://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html):

> Only the `RENAME TABLE`, `ADD COLUMN`, and `RENAME COLUMN` variants of the `ALTER TABLE` command are supported. Other kinds of `ALTER TABLE` operations such as `DROP COLUMN`, `ALTER COLUMN`, **`ADD CONSTRAINT`**, and so forth are omitted.

Bold emphasis is mine.

So basically you would need to create the constraint at the time when the table is created. For your use case, one solution would be to:

- create a new table (with the foreign key constraint)
- copy the data from the old table
- drop the old table (or better yet, rename it, so you have a backup)
- rename the new table

Comment: So I must create a new table? In order to establish this relationship?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide an answer.